# Make buttons change other buttons with selectors in android xml axml

Tags: android, button, xamarin, selector

I was wondering if it is possible to change style, text, textColor, of one or many button s or **imagebuttons** when a button is pressed, focused, clicked with just XML selectors-items  and **axml** layouts

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:minWidth="25dp"
  android:minHeight="25dp"
  android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/innerlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:gravity="start">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/searchic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbut"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="SEARCH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchlb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:textColor="@drawable/menuwordcolor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playlistic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchic"
        android:background="@drawable/playlistbut"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="PLAYLIST"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/playlistlb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playlistic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:textColor="@drawable/menuwordcolor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favouritesic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playlistic"
        android:background="@drawable/favouritesbut"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="FAVOURITES"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/favouriteslb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favouritesic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playlistic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:textColor="@drawable/menuwordcolor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionsic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/favouritesic"
        android:background="@drawable/actionsbut"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="1" />
    <Button
        android:text="ACTIONS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/actionslb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionsic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/favouritesic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/menuwordcolor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        foo:customFont="Fonts/helvetica-neue-bold.ttf" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here it is the xml file named menuwordcolor... this is just the standard example of xml selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item   android:state_pressed="true"    android:color="#30abd5" />
<item   android:state_pressed="false"   android:color="#ffffff" />
<item   android:state_enabled="true"    android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems have you encountered? It would make helpers help you better.

Comment: You can set for example the state to selected on another button click. And You have to declare the selected true/false state in the selector.